# Connecting to MetaMask wallet via WalletConnect Web3Modal V2 from mobile browser does not give connect prompt in metamask app

Tags: metamask, dapps, react, web3-providers, walletconnect

```
import {
  EthereumClient,
  modalConnectors,
  walletConnectProvider,
} from "@web3modal/ethereum";
import { configureChains, createClient, WagmiConfig } from "wagmi";
import { Web3Modal } from "@web3modal/react";

const chains = [mainnet];

const { provider, webSocketProvider } = configureChains(chains, [
    walletConnectProvider({
      projectId: "projectid",
    }),
  ]);
  const wagmiClient = createClient({
    autoConnect: true,
    connectors: modalConnectors({
      projectId: "projectId",
      version: "2",
      appName: "Test App",
      chains,

    }),
    provider,
    webSocketProvider,
  });

  const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiClient, chains);
  
  return (
  <>
  <WagmiConfig client={wagmiClient}>
<Routes>
  <Route path="/testing" element={<Testing />} />
</Routes>      
  </WagmiConfig>
  <Web3Modal
       projectId="projectId"
       ethereumClient={ethereumClient}
       themeZIndex={1350}
    />
 </>
  )
```

And in testing component i m using web3button like this

```
import {  Web3Button } from "@web3modal/react";
return (
<Web3Button balance="show" />
 )
```

when i press this button in mobile browser it prompts to open metamask as select and go in nothing happens no prompt for connect or anything.
What to do to make it work in mobile browsers ?

Works all good in desktop browser.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@web3-react/walletconnect-connector` to achieve wallet connection in mobile through browser like chrome.

```
import { WalletConnectConnector } from "@web3-react/walletconnect-connector"

const walletconnect = new WalletConnectConnector({
      rpc:{ 1 :"ethereum-rpc"}
    });

 .............

await activate(walletconnect, undefined, true).catch((err) => {
    walletconnect.walletConnectProvider = undefined;
});
```

This will pop up the interface as shown in the picture below, from where you can choose your wallet to connect.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are expecting your Mobile Metamask app to pop up like on your desktop computer browser.

This will not work. This is why there is an internal browser in the mobile version of Metamask.

The work around is to use wallet Connect like Safi mentioned.